# 404 error when changing language on category

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

I've got a shop with two store:

- DE (Store name: DE), (Store view: de, code: de)
- UK (Store name: UK), (Store view: en, code: en)

By default, the shop is DE (German)

I've got a 404 error when : I go to the shop, go on a category and try to change the language to en (English).

I figure out that :

`sitename.com/en/modern-carpets.html?___store=en&___from_store=de` -> work

`sitename.com/en/modern-carpets.html` -> doesn't work

And also that if I switch off my cookies in my browser, everything is working.

I am using magento community 1.9.1.0

Already thank you that you took time to read my issue.

Comment: I´m not sure if this is the same issue but you could read up on this https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Language-switch-error-URLs/td-p/3643 and check for Vinai´s fix on here https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_StoreUrlRewrites

Comment: So I tried the Vinai solution, but was not working for me.

But after research I also figure out that store cookie was not set when the shop was on "en". A very quick fix will be to edit the index.php :     
  
`$uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4);  
  
if ($uri == '/en/') {  
        $mageRunCode = 'en';  
        $mageRunType = 'store';  
        setcookie("store", "en");  
} `  
I guess it's a very dirty solution, but for now it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be come for cookie is not being saved on your store.

- Please check your browser cookie after switching language. There must have one cookie with a name of 'store'.

If you can not found that Then please go the system->configuration->web section and please set up session cookie management on a right way

Comment: I set the cookie domain and the cookie path and now it's work perfectly well !

Comment: Cheers Friend :)