# Magento remove "default" store code from urls

Tags: multistore, url, store-view, stores, magento1.9.2.4

I have installed Magento ce 1.9.2.4 for my website.

Now I have setup the stores in such a way that my every url has store code of the current store, visitor is in, appended to it.

For business(bedrift) store the store code being appended to url like `http://example.com/bedrift` is fine but I want to remove `default` store code from urls so my urls become from `http://example.com/default` to `http://example.com` but the store session is maintained.

I have tried with `.htaccess` but it creates infinite redirects and then browser shows error.

Can anyone help me fix this the Magento way ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `system->Configuration`. Then go to `web` tab. You can see there is an option '`add store code to url` set that option to **no**.. It will remove the default word from your url

Comment: Oh I tried that but that creates error in `bedrift` store redirection, as I cannot change my stores even by clicking the link.

Comment: what do you mean by `bedrift`??

Comment: Consider it an example it is my store code. It means "business".

Comment: and what error you found when you changing the store?

Comment: Well the problem  is when I turn off `Add Store Code to Url` I can change the stores just fine, but when I click on the other links like "Login" or "My Account" the system fails to maintain the store session and redirects me to those pages of the `default` store only.

Comment: then you need to check my answer on here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104169/404-error-when-changing-language-on-category/104329#104329

Comment: I did pass cookie domain `any.example.com` and cookie path `/` in the settings you mentioned. But still store cookies aren't created at all for the site. I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Did you checked your cookie as i said on my answer???

Comment: Yes I did everytime, but no cookie by param name `store` is ever created when I change my store.

Comment: if your site domain is www.example.com then your cookie domain name will be example.com

Comment: That's what I am passing but still not working.

Comment: did you check log??

Comment: No I will in a while

Comment: check those! Might be you can find something

Comment: Checked logs, but only system.log is created that also containing nothing related store/session errors. Also my site is in a subdomain inside a domain, so I need to pass both subdomain and domain in the cookie domain right ?

Comment: Set `Use HTTP Only` to **NO**

Comment: Tried that too, but in my other store (other than `default` i.e. `bedrift`) it always gives 404.

Comment: what is the url??

Comment: http://kaffemesteren.webexpressen.no/bedrift and for default store http://kaffemesteren.webexpressen.no/ works

Comment: on `session cookie management` set use `SID TO FRONTEND` to **NO**

Comment: It is already set to NO, but it's in `Session Validation Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

there is extension developed for it. it solved all problem of default store code(http://example.com/default to http://example.com).

[image]

Extension available on github.   [click here](https://github.com/lalitmohann/magento-hide-default-store-code)

i solved this Problem , i hope that's save others Person here is the details :

1- Download the zip existe in this page : https://github.com/lalitmohann/magento-hide-default-store-code

2- unzip the file and put the folder  in `app/code/community/` and `Bubble_HideDefaultStoreCode.xml` file in `app/etc/modules`

3- In your backoffice go to `System > Tools > Compilation` and click the rebuild button

4- always in backoffice got to `System > Configuration > Web > URL options` and set the attribute "and default store view" to No and save the configuration

5- Clear your cach magento and enjoy your application